# "<StudentProfile: None None None>": "StudentsSubmittedDocument.Students_Enrollment_Records" must be a "StudentsEnrollmentRecord" instance

Tags: django

views.py

```py
    id = request.POST.get('ids')
    studentname = StudentProfile(id=id)

    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    student = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.Student_Users

    V_insert_data = StudentsEnrollmentRecord(
            Student_Users=studentname, Payment_Type=payment,
            Education_Levels=educationlevel,School_Year=schoolyear
        )
        V_insert_data.save()
        insert_doc = StudentsSubmittedDocument(
            Students_Enrollment_Records = studentname,
            Document = myfile
        )
        insert_doc.save()

    return render(request, 'Homepage/pending.html')
```

models.py

```py
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    DoesNotExist = None
    objects = None
    Pending_Request = [
        ('Pending_Request', 'Pending_Request'),
        ('Enrolled', 'Enrolled'),
    ]
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    LRN = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class StudentsSubmittedDocument(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Document_Requirements = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    Document = models.FileField(upload_to='files',null=True,blank=True)
```

How to fix this error? i tried so many times to fix this but i can't, i don't know how to fix this error, i just want to save the `StudentsEnrollmentRecord(Student_Users)` to `StudentsSubmittedDocument(Students_Enrollment_Records)`, by the way this is my error:

```
ValueError at /newEnroll/ Cannot assign "": "StudentsSubmittedDocument.Students_Enrollment_Records" must be a "StudentsEnrollmentRecord" instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your variable `insert_doc`, change your `Students_Enrollment_Records` argument from `studentname` to `V_insert_data`, so it would be like this:

```py
insert_doc = StudentsSubmittedDocument(
    Students_Enrollment_Records = V_insert_data,
    Document = myfile
)
```

The error is clearly saying that your are not assigning the correct instance to your `Students_Enrollment_Records` field in your `StudentsSubmittedDocument` model.

PD: I would suggest you to change the names of your `ForeignKey` fields and make them **singular**, since it's pointing only to one record, and plural names may lead to confusion.